# Injecting Multiple Objects into the object container

Tags: c#, selenium, reporting, specflow, extent

Im trying to introduce ExtentReports into my test suite and im having some issues with context injection, im trying to inject the reporting class into my object container along with my IWebDriver but i get the error message. "The ScenarioContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-Threaded execution. 
This is bugging the heck out of me can anyone see where im going wrong ?

heres a snippet of the hooks class

```
   class Hooks : ReportingStepDefinitions
{

    private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;
    private TestReports _report; 
    private IWebDriver _driver;



    public Hooks (IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;      
    }   

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void initialise()
    {  
        _report = new TestReports();
        _report.startTest();
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\\TestData\Dependencies")
        _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(_driver);
        _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<TestReports>(_report);
}
```

i haven't included the close statements as im pretty sure this is where the issue lies ... all help appreciated

*Editing to Include Stack Trace*

```
Result StackTrace:  
Server stack trace: 
   at SpecResults.ReportingAspect.ReportingMessageSink.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SyncProcessMessage>b__0()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at OCCSpecFlow.Hooks.initialise()
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
   at SpecFlowAutomation.FeatureFiles.HomepageFeature.ScenarioSetup(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
   at SpecFlowAutomation.FeatureFiles.HomepageFeature.ViewingTheHomepageJumps() in C:\Source\dev\AutomationFramework\SpecFlowAutomation\FeatureFiles\HomePage.feature:line 10
--TearDown

Server stack trace: 
   at SpecResults.ReportingAspect.ReportingMessageSink.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SyncProcessMessage>b__0()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at OCCSpecFlow.Hooks.cleanup()
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioEnd()
   at SpecFlowAutomation.FeatureFiles.HomepageFeature.ScenarioTearDown()
Result Message: 
TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException : The ScenarioContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-threaded execution. Try injecting the scenario context to the binding class. See http://go.specflow.org/doc-multithreaded for details.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: where is the issue happening? it doesn't look like its anywhere in the code provided...

Comment: Ive also got the tests themselves that implement this with by calling the element in the constructor like    
    Class test 
    {
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
    private readonly TestReports _report;
    public test(IWebDriver driver, TestReports report)
    {
      _driver = driver; 
      _report = report;
    }

Comment: its when actually run the tests in parallel that the issue seems to arise so it works in sequence no problem

Comment: ok, but which line of code above causes the exception?

Comment: I dont get a specific line as when i debug it runs fine, its only when i run in paralel and it seems that the test doesn't try to run as it fails after 78ms and the test on average is about 30secs each. making an educated guess id assume its during the initializing of the "hooks" class

Comment: please post the stack trace then

Comment: added to the question

Comment: please also add the code from C:\Source\dev\AutomationFramework\SpecFlowAutomation\FeatureFiles\HomePage.feature:line 10.  that is where your problem is.

Comment: Thats a feature file. it has no code in it just gherkin scenarios

Comment: what step is bound at that point?

Comment: line 10 is the scenario header  so " Scenario : Viewing the Homepage Jumps

Comment: ok, thanks. And if you remove the objectContainer related lines does it start to work again (or at least get past that point)?

Comment: If I remove all referances to the reports class it works (Even With the IwebDriver Class there)

Comment: so what's in your reports class?

Comment: are you using ScenarioContext.Current anywhere?

Comment: the reports class is simple and not using ScenarioContext.Current as this method should negate the need for it ( At least for what i need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the Response was due to specflow having a bit of a hiccup when i tried to use this over its own ScenarioContext container. since moving the object container out and returning to the scenario context all started working.